# NIntegrate problem with limits in triple integral

Tags: numerical-integration

So I am trying to solve a triple integral in mathematica, but I am getting errors regarding my limits of integration.

This is my code:

```
NIntegrate[400,{y,-sqrt[{1-x^2/6000^2-z^2/2500^2}*{3000^2}],sqrt[{1-x^2/6000^2-z^2/2500^2}
*{3000^2}]},{x,-sqrt[{1-z^2/2500^2}*{6000^2}],sqrt[{1-z^2/2500^2}*{6000^2}]},{z,-2500,2500}]
```

Trying to solve this yields this error:

```
y = sqrt[{9000000(1-x^2/36000000-z^2/6250000)}] is not a valid limit of integration.
```

What can I do to get around this?

Comment: You're integrating numerically, which requires that your limits are numbers. Try `Integrate` if you want a symbolic result.

Comment: Also, In *Mathematica*, all built-in functions start with capital letters: `sqrt` should be `Sqrt`.

Comment: Keep in mind also the the order of the limits for multiple integrals in *Mathematica* is that the first set of limits corresponds to the outermost integral and the last set of limits corresponds to the innermost integral.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the following will solve your problem.

First we define a function that is 1 in the region of interest and zero elsewhere

```
    R[x_, y_, z_] := 
        If[y^2 < (1 - x^2/6000^2 - z^2/2500^2)*(3000^2), 
             If[x^2 < (1 - z^2/2500^2)*(6000^2), 1, 0], 0]
```

Then, we integrate

```
    NIntegrate[ 400 R[x, y, z], {y, -3000, 3000}, {x, -6000, 6000}, {z, -2500, 2500}]
```

In addition to the issue with sqrt, you were using {} where you should be using ()

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have worked.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the syntax errors noted earlier, if you swap your limits of integration you should get a result.

```
NIntegrate[400, {z, -2500, 2500}, 
 {x, -Sqrt[(1-z^2/2500^2)*(6000^2)],Sqrt[(1-z^2/2500^2)*(6000^2)]}, 
 {y, -Sqrt[(1-x^2/6000^2-z^2/2500^2)*(3000^2)], Sqrt[(1-x^2/6000^2-z^2/2500^2)*(3000^2)]}]
```